# create a newline in a array-string using powershell

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

i'm trying to create a newline in a string to get a formated output of an array. the code:

```
$arr = @(
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = "David";  Article = "TShirt"; Size = "S"}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Eduard"; Article = "extra laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge" + "`r`n" + "TShirt"; Size = "XXL"}
[PSCustomObject]@{Name = "John";  Article = "TShirt"; Size = "M"}
)

$arr
```

i expected this output:

```
Name   Article                         Size
----   -------                         ----
David  TShirt                          S   
Eduard extra laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge      XXL
       TShirt
David  TShirt                          M
```

but i get this:

```
Name   Article                            Size
----   -------                            ----
David  TShirt                             S   
Eduard extra laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge...      XXL 
David  TShirt                             M
```

what is the trick?

Comment: for the last line, do `$arr | Format-Table -Wrap`

Comment: great. this is the solution. great thanks. how can i flag this answer as "solved"?

Comment: You couldn't accept, because it was a comment. I have now added it as answer so it can be accepted by clicking the faint checkmark icon next to it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is the default PowerShell way of truncating long lines in table format.

You can see the code does what you expect if you change the last line into

```
$arr | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Output on console:

> ```
> Name   Article                            Size
> ----   -------                            ----
> David  TShirt                             S   
> Eduard extra laaaaaaaaaaaaaaaarge         XXL 
>        TShirt                                 
> John   TShirt                             M
> ```